# Duda ajax en término "term"

Tags: ajax

En este codigo para ajax tengo la duda de si `.term` es una funcion de ajax o forma parte de la librería `select2.js`. He buscado en la documentación de esta librería pero no encuentro nada sobre term. ¿A que hace referencia `term`?¿para qué sirve?

```
$( ".cliente" ).select2({
ajax: {
    url: "ajax/clientes_json.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    delay: 250,
    data: function (params) {
        return {
            q: params.term // search term
        };
    },
    processResults: function (data) {
        return {
            results: data
        };
    },
    cache: true
    },
    minimumInputLength: 2
  }).on('change', function (e){
        var email = $('.cliente').select2('data')[0].email;
        var telefono = $('.cliente').select2('data')[0].telefono;
        var direccion = $('.cliente').select2('data')[0].direccion;
        $('#email').html(email);
        $('#telefono').html(telefono);
        $('#direccion').html(direccion);
  })
});
```

Comment: Es una libreria de `select2` aqui una doc https://select2.org/searching

Answer (score 2):

***request.term*** es una variable dentro de Autocompletar. Son los caracteres que un usuario ha escrito hasta ahora, mientras completa un cuadro de entrada que tiene Autocompletado adjunto. Así que si escribo "Mike", request.term es "M", luego "Mi", luego "Mik", luego "Mike".

[Fuente](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/what-is-request-term)